# Does primefaces fluidGrid provide a rowIndexVar or rowKeyVar attribute?

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am using a reponsive grid    which is an extension of primefaces. However I can't seem to figure out how to get the index of items within the grid.

I tried **rowIndexVar**  and **rowKeyVar** and they don't seem to work. I've included a snippet of my code below.

```
<pe:fluidGrid value="#{resultList}" var="showvar" rowKeyVar="rowKey" fitWidth="true" hasImages="true">
...  
</pe:fluidGrid >

...
<h:link onclick="$(callme('#{showvar.showId}','#{rowKey}'));">                      
    <h:graphicImage  url="#{showvar.showImage}"/>                               
</h:link>
```

....

```
<h:outputScript>
  function callme(id,row){
    alert(id);
    alert(row);
  }
</h:outputScript>
```

---

I could just declare an unique index variable in my object  and reference it like below, but I'd like to know if fluidGird offers a rowKeyVar attribute.

```
<ui:param name="itemIndex" value="#{showvar.showIndex}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is the `varContainerId`

> **varContainerId**
>   Name of the request-scoped variable which contains the prefix of the client Id within pe:fluidGridItem. This property allows to get the whole clientId of a component within pe:dynaFormControl. The whole client Id is sometimes required for JavaScript or RequestContext.update(...).

See also: http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-ext/views/fluidGrid.jsf